# ASP.NET Core MVC view Ajax: retrieved list shows up as 'undefined' in table

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to retrieve the values from a `List<>` in my controller to populate a table in my view. I can get the data and call the Ajax method to populate the table, but all fields show up as 'undefined'

I also tried `RedirectToAction` in the controller to send the data to a new view as a list and I can see the data going to the 'foreach' part of the code --but when it completes, the view does not get show on the screen.

Can someone please help me to show the table?

Model:

```
public class WorkItemInfo
{
    public string WorkItemId { get; set; }
    public string WorkItemType { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfWork { get; set; }
    public string WorkItemState { get; set; }
    public string WorkItemTitle { get; set; }
    public string WorkItemAreaPath { get; set; }
    public string WorkItemIterationPath { get; set; }
    public string WorkItemTags { get; set; }
    public string WorkItemCreatedDate { get; set;}
}
```

Controller method:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> PopulateWorkItemPartialTable(string selectedAreaPathItems, string selectedIterationPathItems)
{
        //Get the retrieved work items
        List<WorkItemInfo> retrievedWorkItems =
            await GetAllSelectedWorkItems(selectedAreaPathItems, selectedIterationPathItems);

        return Json(retrievedWorkItems);
}
```

View script:

```
function GetSelectedAreaPathChildren2() {
        var selectedAreaPathItems = '';
        $("#AreaPathMultiSelectDropdownList :selected").each(function () {
            selectedAreaPathItems += this.value + ";";
        });

        var selectedIterationPathItems = '';
        $("#IterationPathMultiSelectDropdownList :selected").each(function () {
            selectedIterationPathItems += this.value + ";";
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("PopulateWorkItemPartialTable", "PbcAzureDevOps")',
            //contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            //dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            data: { selectedAreaPathItems, selectedIterationPathItems },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    var row = $('<tr><td>' + item.WorkItemId
                        + '</td><td>' + item.WorkItemType
                        + '</td><td>' + item.TypeOfWork
                        + '</td><td>' + item.WorkItemState
                        + '</td><td>' + item.WorkItemTitle
                        + '</td><td>' + item.WorkItemAreaPath
                        + '</td><td>' + item.WorkItemIterationPath
                        + '</td><td>' + item.WorkItemTags
                        + '</td><td>' + item.WorkItemCreatedDate
                        + '</td></tr>');
                        $('#myTable').append(row);
                });
            }
        });
}
```

View button:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="BLAH" onclick="GetSelectedAreaPathChildren2()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Expected result: when clicking the button, "myTable" is populated with the retrieved rows

Actual result: "myTable" is populated with 'undefined' (note the table has the correct rows and columns expected)

Any help is appreciated.

Also, is there some thing that needs to be done if I wanted to send the data to a different view? I tried that and changed the Controller method to `IAsyncResult`, but while it gets the data, the view is not shown.

Thanks.

Comment: When you debug the AJAX success handler, what does `item` (and/or `data`) actually contain?

Comment: This is what I'm seeing in the Network/Response tabs in Developer Tools: [{"workItemId":"10000022","workItemType":"Feature","typeOfWork":null,"workItemState":"Done","workItemTitle":"TITLE HERE ....

Comment: A typo then?  JavaScript is case-sensitive.  `WorkItemId` != `workItemId`

Comment: WOW! Totally misread the output and you are correct David, it was the case-sensitivity. Great catch, and THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

David answered my question, the issue turned out to be the case sensitivity.